# Creating vectors with only the arrowhead in gnuplot

Tags: vector, gnuplot

How does one create a vector without the line and just the arrowhead?

There is an option called "nohead" which removed the head of the arrow, but I want to do the opposite, remove the line of the vector and only keep the head.

Most preferably also be able to re-scale the size of this arrowhead based on a single number.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise? Do you `set arrow`, or do you `plot ... with vectors`? Do you want to scale the arrow based on some value in a data file, or by some factor which you define at the beginning of your script? And do you have gnuplot version 5?

Comment: - I use plot ... with vectors (but if you could also show me how to do it with set arrow than that would be great as well). 
- the scale of the arrow head based on some value in the data file correct, so I already use 4 columns for the vector itself (x,y,dx,dy) and the last column should be a number between 0 and 1 on which gnuplot scales the arrowhead to the max size for a value of 1 and to a minimum size at value 0 and something in between for the other values.)
- gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3

Comment: the default one (I believe its called wxt or something)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found some useful advices on [TeXExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132226/how-do-i-add-only-arrowheads-to-an-eps-gnuplot-figure), seems like exactly what you were looking for.
The right command that you need is `fixed` which allows to plot only the head

```
set style arrow 11 head filled size 7, 20, 60 fixed lt -1
```

Otherwise have a look on [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/feature-requests/369/), were you find the originally solved question!

EDIT: The result will look something like this
[image: Fixed]