# Plot vectors only head with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I need to plot only the vectors head, but using the following

```
plot 'plot.txt' u 1:2:($3*factor):($4*factor) w vector lc rgb 'black'
```

I obtain all the vectors. I only want the head.

so I need to delete a part of a vector mantaining only the head. How can I plot this?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112482/2604213

Comment: @Christoph thank you, I saw it but it does not solve my problems. I need to plot only the heads for all the vectors, not for only one. Could yo write here the code I need to enter to gnuplot to do it? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer linked by @Christoph indeed contains the key ingredient:

> The right command that you need is `fixed` which allows to plot only the head

However, one should be perhaps slightly more specific here. The keyword `fixed` per se does not produce "head-only arrows". Its primary purpose is to guarantee that the size of the arrows is independent of the length of the vectors. So in order to produce an arrow with its head only, one might merely shift the starting point of the arrow in the direction of the end point until it is "hidden" inside of the head. That's why the right inner-most arrow in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112482/5351549) appears to be formed by its head only - the body (line) is just "covered" by the head.

So in order to do this in practice, one might proceed as:

```
reset

set terminal pngcairo
set output 'fig.png'

$db <<EOF
0.0 0.0    1  1
3.0 0.0   -1  1
3.0 3.0   -1 -1
0.0 3.0    1 -1
EOF

set xr [0:3]
set yr [0:3]

set size square

set xtics 0,1,3 in
set ytics 0,1,3 in
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2

unset key

set style arrow 1 head filled size screen 0.05,45 fixed lc rgb 'royalblue'
set style arrow 2 head filled size screen 0.05,45 fixed lc rgb 'dark-spring-green'

factor=0.5

sigma=0.99

plot \
    $db using 1:2:(factor*$3):(factor*$4) with vectors as 2,\
    $db using ($1+sigma*$3):($2+sigma*$4):((1-sigma)*$3):((1-sigma)*$4) with vectors as 1
```

The first part of the `plot` statement produces arrows (green) scaled with factor 0.5. Since their length is still significant, they appear with head as well as with the body. In the second part, there is the shift factor `0<=sigma<=1` - the statement `($1+sigma*$3):($2+sigma*$4):((1-sigma)*$3):((1-sigma)*$4)` then requests an arrow with the same endpoint as before (for example, sum of the first and third columns is independent of sigma), but with shifted origin along the direction of the arrow (`sigma=0` recovers original arrow, `sigma=1` would produce zero-length arrow). Thus if `sigma` is sufficiently close to `1`, only the arrow heads are visible:

[image]