# Arrows on lines

Tags: gnuplot

I have function of an electric field lines:

```
set isosamples 55, 55
set contour base
set cntrparam levels incremental -1.6,0.2,1.6
unset  surface
splot [-4:4] [-2.2:2.2] (y*(1+1/(x**2 + y**2)))
```

How to put arrows on this curves, sey in position of x=2?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way how to achieve this would be as follows:

```
set isosamples 200, 200
set contour base
unset  surface
set cntrparam levels incremental -2,0.2,2

set xr [-4:4]
set yr [-3:3]

x_ref = 2

f(x,y) = (y*(1+1/(x**2 + y**2)))
g(x,y) = 2*x*y / ( (x*x + y*y)**2 + (x*x + y*y) - 2*y*y )

set table 'meta.levels.dat'
splot f(x, y)

set table 'meta.pnts.dat'
splot f(x_ref, y)

unset key
unset table
set terminal pngcairo enhanced size 600, 400
set output 'fig.png'

set style arrow 1 head filled size screen 0.01,30 fixed lc rgb 'dark-red'

set size ratio -1

delta = 0.01

plot \
    'meta.levels.dat' w l lc rgb 'black', \
    'meta.pnts.dat' every 1:1:0:0:0:0 u (x_ref-delta):($2-g(x_ref,$2)*delta):(delta):(g(x_ref,$2)*delta) with vectors as 1
```

The strategy is to:

1. first generate contours of the function of interest (`f(x,y)` in the script above) and save them into a file via `set table`
2. for chosen value of `x` (for example `x_ref=2`), generate contours of `f(x_ref, y)`. Since this function does not depend on `x`, the generated contours will be just lines parallel with the `x-`axis, thus in order to plot the points of intersection with the contours of `f(x,y)`, one can take just the first point of each block (each contour) and plot it with `x`-coordinate set to `x_ref`.
3. using the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#General_formula_for_derivative_of_implicit_function) for the derivative of an implicit function, calculate the slope of the contours (this derivative is defined above as `g(x,y)`)
4. finally, one has the positions for the arrows as well as their slope so that one can directly plot it using, e.g., the `with vectors` style. Above, the `delta` parameters specifies a small displacement in the `x`-direction - this is in order to [achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44280309/5351549) that the only the head of the arrow is visible.

In the end, the graph looks like:
[image]